# PHP embed a variable in HTML

Tags: php, html, input

I am trying to embed a raw PHP variable `$nombre` into the HTML, here is the PHP:

```
Edit <?php echo $nombre; ?> .
<form action="getfile.php" method="post" name="uploadForm" id="uploadForm"
enctype="multipart/form-data"  ><br>

Complete the information below <br></br>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Nombre &nbsp;</td> 
<td>
  <input name="nombre" value="<?php=$nombre?>" type="text" id="nombre" />&nbsp;
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The first `<?php echo $nombre; ?>` shows the correct value, but inside `<input>` tag it prints blankstring.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Side note: You should do a `htmlspecialchars()` on `$nombre` if it's not already been run on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried the following code and it worked

```
<?php
$nombre = "hello"; 
?>

Let's edit  <?php echo $nombre; ?>.
<form action="getfile.php" method="post" name="uploadForm" id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data"  ><br>
Complete the information below <br></br>
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td>Nombre  &nbsp;</td> <td><input name="nombre" value="<?php echo $nombre?>" type="text" id="nombre" />&nbsp;</td>
        </tr></table>
</form>
```

Comment: I was not sending the  right values,, and I realized thanks to you :) Sometimes it is necessary to start from the beggining

Answer (score 3):

You have `<?php=$nombre?>` instead of `<?=$nombre ?>` or `<?php echo $nombre ?>` in your input tag.

Comment: it mixes the short open tag convention with the full open tag  convention.

Comment: this was one of the combinations. I have tried yours too, no success neither

Comment: @mujer then show the generated HTML so we don't have to guess.